# How do I get the email from an ID when using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So let's say I've got a hypothetical:

@post.user_id

where User has_many posts and I'm using devise,

I'd like to do something like:

@post.user_id.email but this fails; what's the elegant way of getting the email address here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `@post.user.email`, assuming your models have right associations